# Execute SQL Server Stored Procedure in R

Tags: sql-server, r, stored-procedures

I have a problem when I execute a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure in R. The execution in R follows as:

---

```
library(RODBC)

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQLServer};server=xxx;database=xxx;trusted_connection=true') 

data <-sqlquery(dbhandle, "EXEC ihshsf35.FPR_GET_PF10  @tipo_pes='F' , @date_process='2016-11-30'") 

odbcCloseAll()
```

---

The error that appears in R:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
 character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

---

The stored procedure calls a characteristic and a date to extracts information from the database:

```
Procedure [ihshsf35].[FPR_GET_PF10] 
( 
        @tipo_pes varchar(1), 
        @date_process as datetime 
) 
AS 
BEGIN
```

---

I don´t have problems executing this stored procedure from other systems like SAS and SPSS, but when I try in R brings me a error.
Note: In SQL server the data has the format "aaaa-mm-dd" the same I asking in R

Can anyone can help me with the problem in R?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your stored procedure's returned query. Are there non-dates values in any datetime column? Are you creating or casting datetime in query? Error is not the stored proc call but trying to build dataframe from query with a problematic datetime field.

Comment: The stored procedure works in all system: SPSS, Sql Server, Visual Basic, but not in R. There aren´t non-dates values in any datetime column. The only data could have problem is 1753-01-01. I don´t create or casting datetime in query. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I see what the problem was and how to solve it. Need to use the parameter `as.is=T` with the function `sqlExecute`:

```
data <- sqlExecute(dbhandle, "exec FPR_GET_PJ  @tipo_pes='J', @date_process='2016-12-31'", 
                   fetch = TRUE, as.is=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you be wiling to give the following a try?

`@date_process` is expecting a date-time value, but I don't expect that would make much difference.  I chose to use `RODBCext` because 1) safer from SQL Injection, and 2) Using single quotes (`'`) has led me into more headaches with SQL than I care to recount.

```
library(RODBCext)

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQLServer};server=xxx;database=xxx;trusted_connection=true') 

data <-sqlExecute(dbhandle, 
                  "EXEC ihshsf35.FPR_GET_PF10  @tipo_pes=? , @date_process=?",
                  data = list(tipo_pes = 'F',
                              date_process = '2016-11-30 00:00:00'),
                  fetch = TRUE) 

odbcCloseAll()
```

On the single quote issue, it's also worth trying a reversal of your single and double quotes.  So `'EXEC ihshsf35.FPR_GET_PF10 @tipo_pes = "F", @date_process = "2016-11-30"'`.

Comment: I did a try with your suggestions but with the same results.                       Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. In addition: Warning message: closing unused RODBC handle 14. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I also try:                                                                                                        oe<-as.POSIXct(strptime("2016-12-31 23:00:000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"));   data <-sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'exec ihshsf35.FPR_GET_PF10  @tipo_pes="F", @date_process="oe"'; but with the same results. Note that all datetime doesn´t have any NA